# read tar.gz file into binary string python

Tags: python, base64

I have to upload a tar ball (tar.gz) file into s3 but by calling internal API.

The API accepts base64 encoded string.

Is there a way to convert tar.gz file to bytes string and then convert to base64 string in python?

Comment: Opening the file and reading the contents would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file as a byte stream is pretty straightforward:

```
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

The extra "b" is for "binary mode"

Converting that into base64 is also simple, you only need to use the handy `base64` module.:

```
import base64
data = base64.b64encode(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. Is there a way that I can read files in binary mode and create a tar ball in memory and use the compressed binary string as push data ?@Michael Guffre